# How can i concatenate two fields in a MS Access 2007 Table and display in a third field?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

[image]

I want to concatenate 'First Name' and 'Last Name' and then display into the 'Customer Name' field.

I am using MS Access 2007.

I explored on this, I got to know that we can write a VB Script as below on the Customer Name column name itself:

```
Customer Name: [First Name]& " " &[Last Name]
```

but it gives error

In MS Access 2013, there is an option of 'Calculated Field' to do this easily. I am not sure how to do this in 2007.

Please suggest.

Comment: `select *, [First Name] & " " & [Last Name] from T` should work fine. What query are you trying and what is the error?

Comment: Don't bother creating an extra column, you can always add the two together whenever you need "Full Name"

Answer (score 0):

-Write a Query to return all fields from the table

-use `Customer Name: [First Name]& " " &[Last Name]` as formula

-use the query instead fo the table as source for further manipulations